# Dar play em um audio começando nos 10 segundos

Tags: jquery, áudio, html5-audio

Estou controlando alguns audios em um site e estou precisando que alguns audios específicos comecem no segundo 10, até agora está assim:

```
var minhaMusica = new Audio();
minhaMusica.src = 'musica.mp3";
minhaMusica.play();
```

Precisaria algo assim (sei que não funciona, só para ilustrar):

```
 var minhaMusica = new Audio();
 minhaMusica.src = 'musica.mp3";
 minhaMusica.play().currentTime(10);
```

Existe algo nesse estilo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui:

```
var minhaMusica = new Audio();
minhaMusica.src = 'musica.mp3";
minhaMusica.currentTime = 10;
minhaMusica.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Na documentação do [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) (HTMLMediaElement) existe o `currentTime`,:

```
audio.currentTime = 10
```

Por exemplo:

```js
audio = window.document.querySelector("audio");
if (!(audio instanceof HTMLMediaElement)) {
   alert('O audio não é um HTMLMediaElement');
}

window.document.querySelector("[skip]").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  audio.currentTime += e.target.getAttribute("skip");
});

window.document.querySelector("[play]").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  audio.play();
});
```

```html
<button skip="10">Avançar para 10s</button>
<button play>Começar</button>

<hr>

<audio controls="true">
  <source src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/5f3bc9c84ccb48505f511ee6ef6cc690483d9f5d" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```